# Unable to catch any events in a controller

Tags: extjs, model-view-controller

First of all, I have this file structure:

```
Module1/
init.js
    store/
      ...
    view/
      Module1Panel.js
    controller/
      Module1Controller.js

Module2/
init.js
    store/
      ...
    view/
      Module2Panel.js
    controller/
      Module2Controller.js
```

In Module1 I load Module2 like this:

```
#module1/init.js
...
Ext.application({
    paths:{
        'Module2':'/app/Module2'   
    },
    ...
    controllers:['Module1Controller','Module2.controller.Module2Controller']
});
```

As a result of all this I see in the console, that all controllers, all views, all stores and models are loaded. At this moment everything looks just perfect, except one nasty thing - controller from Module2 does not catch any events. By this I mean, that I can't make this code work

```
#Module2Controller.js
...
init:function(){
    this.control({
        'Module2Panel button[itemId=test2]':{
             click:this.click(); 
        }
    });
    console.log('Hello from init'); //this works
},
click:function(){
    console.log('Hello from click'); //this does not work on button click
}
```

I think I know how the controller should work. At least, Module1controller works perfectly. I do it dot by dot and line by line. So, there shouldn't be any significant error, I think. Otherwise, I would not see all my controllers, views, stores and models being loaded. Please, advise me how can I debug my code and catch the error. PS. What I think, is that there is only one thing special for Module2, that is, it is loaded from Module1. So, it's not a "normal" module and, therefore, there may exist some missing initialisation steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining event handlers you don't call them. Just define. So, replace

```
click:this.click();
```

with

```
click: this.click
```

Comment: Yeah, there is a mistake. +1 for you, -1 for me =)